# Click Handler immediately invoked in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've written a click handler to resolve a download button to the google play store URL.

The problem is that when the page loads, the URL is immediately visited.

The click handler is nested inside an onPress attribute, and I don't press anything, so I'm struggling to understand why this would be happening.

Any help would be appreciated!

OpenURL.js:

```
'use strict';
import React, {
  Component,
  PropTypes,
  Linking,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class OpenURLButton extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick(url) {
    console.log(url);
    console.log('handling click! this is : ');
    console.dir(this);
    Linking.canOpenURL(this.props.url).then(supported => {
      if (supported) {
        Linking.openURL(this.props.url);
      } else {
        console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + this.props.url);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('logging "this" inside render inside OpenURL.js:');
    console.dir(this);
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleClick(this.props.appStoreUrl)}>
        <Text>Download {this.props.appStoreUrl}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

}


OpenURLButton.propTypes = {
  url: React.PropTypes.string,
}

export default OpenURLButton;
```

Inventory.js:

```
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.ImageBanner} source={{uri: selectedInventory.bannerImage}} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.ListGridItemCaption}>
        <Image style={[styles.ImageThumb, styles.ImageGridThumb]} source={{uri: selectedInventory.thumbImage}} />
        <Text style={styles.Text} key="header">{name}</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>{selectedInventory.description}</Text>
        <OpenURLButton url={selectedInventory.appStoreUrl}/>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```xml
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleClick(this.props.appStoreUrl)}>
  <Text>Download {this.props.appStoreUrl}</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

To:

```xml
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.handleClick(this.props.appStoreUrl)}}>
  <Text>Download {this.props.appStoreUrl}</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

With the change you are creating anonymous function that are calling on "your" method. This *will* work.

Comment: Sorry to necro this but I've tried (and failed) to find documentation about why the use of an anonymous function is required to prevent the method from firing on page load.

Is there somewhere where the reasoning behind the difference between the behaviour of `onPress`/any event handlers when passed in a "local" (lives in the same class) method vs a "remote" (i.e: this.props.doStuff) method.

I have the problem described above when I use local methods and I'd rather understand why then do something "just because". Many thanks.